# How to assign specific ID to Kafka Topic Partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic, kafka-partition

I am new to Apache Kafka. I want to assign a our user id as id to the topic partition. Is there a way to assign our own user-id to partition. I did research for couple hours on this, but didn't find any article related to assigning an ID to partition.

While publishing a message to Topic I want to use the user-id as key. So that all messages goes into the same partition. And I want to make sure that one partition should contain only one user related messages.

Can I use this user-id in consumers while consuming messages from partition?

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Id generation logic is up to your own application/services.

The default behavior of Kafka `DefaultPartitioner` is to place all same IDs into the same partition, ordered by arrival time (not necessarily producer time without extra producer configuration); there is nothing you need to do for this

> Can I use this user-id in consumers

It's just the record key, so yes...

If you mean you want to assign consumer certain partitions based on the ID, then you'd need to reverse the `DefaultPartitioner` hash function

Comment: I want to make sure that one partition should contain only one user related messages. With "DefaultPartitioner" multiple user messages are coming to same partition.

Comment: One user-id cannot exist in multiple partitions. One partition **can** hold multiple users. This is what allows you to scale the process to multiple users beyond your original partition count. There's no way to fix this without using a topic, or cluster, per "user account"

Comment: If we allow multiple users to same partition, if user1 have 10k records and after that user2 produced 10 records, then user2 have to wait until user1 records consumed. So I want to have one partition for each user.

Comment: Okay, well, that's the tradeoff for the architecture you've made. How many users do you plan on having? Kafka shouldn't be used to handle tens of thousands of partitions for a single topic. You also shouldn't constantly increase partition count for when you reach capacity

Comment: We have 1k users that means we have to create 1k partitions. Is there a way to maintain 1-to-1 relationship between partition and user ?

Comment: You're welcome to write your own Partitioner, that maintains some state based on how many users get created. As soon as you reach some number of users (say 80% of all partitions) you can increase the partition count... However, I don't see this as sustainable

Answer (score 0):

To implement the interface, you can customize the partition logic:

```
public interface Partitioner
```

detail: https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html#partition-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-byte:A-java.lang.Object-byte:A-org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster-